# Can i call my function in the while loop?

Tags: python, function

Generate a random number between 1 and 9 (including 1 and 9). Ask the user to guess the number, then tell them whether they guessed too low, too high, or exactly right. (_Hint: remember to use the user input lessons from the very first exercise

Extras:

Keep the game going until the user types “exit”
Keep track of how many guesses the user has taken, and when the game ends, print this out.

I actually cant figure out why my program is not printing the prints in the if clauses. Did i call wrong the first fucntions in my while loop?

```
import random

def cpu_guess():
    cpu_number=random.randint(1,9)
    return cpu_number
print(cpu_guess())

def player_guess():
    player_number=input('Digit a number between 1 and 9\n')
    return player_number

def game():
    r_guesses=0
    w_guesses=0
    while player_guess()!='exit':
        if int(player_guess())>int(cpu_guess()):
            print('Higher value than generated')
            w_guesses+=1
        elif int(player_guess())<int(cpu_guess()):
            print('Lower value than generated')
        else:
            print('You have entered the right value')
            r_guesses+=1
    return r_guesses,w_guesses
print(game())
```

I am not sure i can do this   while player_guess()!='exit':  Do i need to creat a variable like this 
guess=player_guess()   and write    while guess!='exit'

Comment: You keep calling `player_guess` over and over, which asks for input. Are you sure it's not just stuck waiting for you to type something?

Comment: so you recomend to creat a variable?

Comment: Yes. Think of how many times `input` is being called in the code you have.

Comment: The same also applies for `cpu_guess()`. Your computer basically changes its guess every time you call that function.

Comment: my computer print infinites you have entered the right value over and over

Comment: you recomend me to store my functions name in a variable

Comment: but the endeless print continues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `player_guess` over and over, and each time you call it, it will stop and wait for input. It's getting stuck waiting for input potentially three times per loop. Call the function once and save the result in a variable:

```
def game():
    r_guesses = 0
    w_guesses = 0
    guess = None # Save it here

    while guess != 'exit':
        guess = player_guess()
        if guess > int(cpu_guess()):
            print('Higher value than generated')
            w_guesses+=1
        elif guess < int(cpu_guess()):
            print('Lower value than generated')
        else:
            print('You have entered the right value')
            r_guesses += 1
    return r_guesses, w_guesses
print(game())
```

And then, as noted in the comments, do something similar for the computer's guess. The computers turn is changing constantly, so you may get through all the checks and get unexpected results for that reason. Think about what happens when those functions are called.

Comment: i only did not understand why the need of putting none.  The program states that the orogram only ends when we write exit

Comment: @Luismaia1994 Because `guess` needs a value before the loop starts so that the condition has something to check. I guess actually since you're just checking against the String "exit", it's unnecessary. I'll edit. Often you need a half-usable value before the loop starts, and if that isn't possible, you need to use a "sentinel" and check for it like I did here.

Comment: @Luismaia1994 Also note how I spaced things out. If you want, post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) later, and we can help give you general suggestions to write better code (like making it look nicer and run better).

Answer (score 2):

You keep changing the values in the middle of the loop; this is chaos, not a logic game.

```
# Get a player guess and see whether it's "exit"
while player_guess()!='exit':

    # Get a new guess; also make a new target number.
    if int(player_guess())>int(cpu_guess()):
        print('Higher value than generated')
        w_guesses+=1

    # Get a new guess; also make a new target number.
    elif int(player_guess())<int(cpu_guess()):
        print('Lower value than generated')
    else:
        print('You have entered the right value')
        r_guesses+=1
```

Instead, you need to make *one* target number the player is trying to guess.  Do *not* change it during the game.  Within the loop, have the player guess *once*: do *not* ask for more input until you've properly evaluated that guess and responded.

```
# Get a player guess and see whether it's "exit"
target = int(cpu_guess())
player_input = player_guess()
while player_input != 'exit':

    guessed_num = int(player_input)
    if guessed_num > target:
        print('Higher value than generated')
        w_guesses+=1

    elif ...
```

See how that works?  Don't go back to your input routine until you're done with the current guess.  Don't go back to the target generation routine until the player is done guessing the previous number.

Comment: if i input your code it runs lower, higher ou equal value than generated forever

Comment: I disagree.  If you input my code *as it appears*, it fails to run at all, because I didn't rewrite your entire program for you.  To get a working program, you need to start with this code, but then extend it with the advice I included.

Comment: obviously i did not run only that

Comment: i add the other to functions and the rest of the if sentences